# Apache Camel Memory Leak with Kafka Producer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel 2.20.2 (together with Spring Boot 1.5.8) to route message coming in through MQTT to two other services, one is HTTP/SOAP (works ok) and the other one is Apache Kafka.

After an initial run overnight with about 320 messages per minute I noticed that the process got extremely slow. After some profiling, I found that the Kafka Route produces a memory leak (disabled the HTTP route to be sure).

```
@Component
public class Router extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationProperties param;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Starting MqttKafkaBridgeApplication with:\n" + param.toString());

        // MQTT Consumer
        from("mqtt:vernemq?"
                + "host=tcp:MqttHost:MqttPort...")
        .transform(body().convertToString())
        .log("Recieved : "+body().convertToString())
        .multicast()
        .stopOnException().to( "direct:kafka");

        // Kafka Producer
        from("direct:kafka")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader(KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY, 0);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY, "1");
                }
            })
            .to("kafka:" +  "kafkaTopic"  +
                "?brokers=kafkaHost:KafkaPort;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Camel, but as far as I can see, my config is quite simple?
I can see the message arriving on the Kafka cluster, so no idea why the memory isn't freed?

Screenshot from visualvm, one can watch the count of the byte and the char array grow with every message:
[image]

Comment: Maybe I am reading it wrong but isn't that the actual Kafka objects and not the Camel Route parts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, it looks like Camel uses as much memory as you give it, as soon as GC runs everything looks fine.
I'm now running the application without any major changes in a docker container and did not have any memory related problems.